# Determining $1$-th simplicial homology group of the Möbius strip.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

Let $\underline  {\mathcal M}$ be the underlying s$\Delta$-set of the Möbius strip. I am trying to compute the simplicial homology groups of $\underline {\mathcal M}.$ I find that the $0$-th simplicial homology group $H_0^{\Delta} \left (\underline {\mathcal M} \right ) \cong \Bbb Z$ and the $n$-th simplicial homology group $H_n^{\Delta} \left (\underline {\mathcal M} \right ) = 0,$ for $n \geq 2.$ While computing the $1$-th simplicial homology group $H_1^{\Delta} \left (\underline {\mathcal M} \right )$ I find that $$H_1^{\Delta} \left (\underline {\mathcal M} \right ) = \langle a - b + c, d \rangle / \langle a + b -d, a - c + d \rangle.$$ But I can't able to simplify it further. Would anybody please help me in this regard?

Thanks for reading.

**EDIT** $:$

[image]

Comment: I think it's $\Bbb Z^2.$ Because we have $a + b = d$ and $a - c = -d$ and $2a = c - b.$ So $\langle a - b + c, d \rangle = \langle 3a, a + b \rangle \cong \mathbb Z^2,$ since $3a$ and $a + b$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you got the generators of $Z_1$? I can come up with a triangulation that yields the generators of $B_1$ you wrote down, but then $a-b+c$ is not a cycle.

Comment: @Christoph is my triangulation correct? I have added a picture. I have found two $0$-simplices, four $1$-simplices and two $2$-simplices in the triangulation of $\underline {\mathcal M}.$

Comment: Yes, but $\partial(a-b+c)=3v-3w\neq 0$. You should get $Z_1=\langle d,a+b,a-c\rangle$.

Comment: I have computed the face maps $d_0$ and $d_1.$ I have found that $$d_0 (a) = v, d_0(b) = w, d_0(c) = v, d_0(d) = w$$ and $$d_1 (a) = w, d_1(b) = v, d_1(c) = w, d_1(d) = w.$$ Are they correct @Christoph? Then the map $d^1 : \mathbb Z \{a,b,c,d\} \longrightarrow \mathbb Z \{v,w\}$ is defined as $$d^1 : = d_0 - d_1.$$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Christoph then what is the kernel of $d^1\ $?

Comment: He just told you above: $Z_{1}=\langle d, a+b, a-c \rangle $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix of $d^1\colon \mathbb Z\{a,b,c,d\}\to\mathbb Z\{v,w\}$ is obtained from your triangulation as
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & -1 & 0\end{pmatrix},
$$
which has rank $1$ and hence the kernel is free of rank $3$. It is generated by $d$, $a+b$ and $a-c$. Hence, we get
$$
H_1 = \frac{\langle d,a+b,a-c\rangle}{\langle a+b-d,a-c+d\rangle} = \frac{\langle d,a+b-d,a-c+d\rangle}{\langle a+b-d,a-c+d\rangle} \cong\langle d\rangle\cong\mathbb Z.
$$

Comment: Oh! My bad. I have now computed. If $pa + qb + rc + sd \in \text {ker} d ^1.$ Then I find that $p-q + r = 0.$ Hence $p = q - r.$ That will give us $\text {ker} (d ^1) = \langle a + b, c - a, d \rangle.$ Sorry for my horrible algebraic manipulation.

Comment: So the Möbius strip and the circle have the same simplicial homology groups. Right?

Comment: @Anacardium That's right. In fact, they are homotopy equivalent! You can deformation retract the Möbius strip onto its central circle.

Comment: Can you give a triangulation of the genus-$2$-surface which makes the simplicial homology groups easier to compute. I have found one such by joining the opposite edges of the octagon whose edges are identified in a certain way. But this figure contains one $0$-simplex, twelve $1$-simplices and eight $2$-simplices which makes things complicated. Can it be simplified in a certain way? This problem is given in our lecture notes as one of the exercises but I am unable to figure it out.